# Turning meta off

Tags: script

#### About

Based on [Is there any way I can turn Stack Overflow Meta off?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407035/is-there-any-way-i-can-turn-stack-overflow-meta-off), this will give anyone a break from a site meta. It removes:

- The home page, both "Featured on Meta" and "Hot Meta Posts"
- Meta link from "CURRENT COMMUNITY" in the upper right hamburger menu.
- "Meta user"-link from user profiles
- Meta achievements in the achievement dropdown.
- Inbox-elements from meta.

Note: It does not remove the inbox indicator. But it does remove the items once the inbox icon has been clicked. Likewise with achievements.

#### Screenshot

If one accidentally goes to a meta post, this will be the presented page:

[image: Meta NO!]

#### Sites

The script only works for [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), but can be expanded to any site by adding two lines to the script header:

```js
// @include      /^https://meta.<siteurl>/
// @include      /^https://<siteurl>/(?:(?:questions|users).*)?$/
```

Example for [Super User](https://superuser.com/):

```js
// @include      /^https://meta.superuser.com/
// @include      /^https://superuser.com/(?:(?:questions|users).*)?$/
```

#### Download

[GitHub](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/tree/main/StackMetaOff) | [Install](https://github.com/Scratle/fiddlings/raw/main/StackMetaOff/StackMetaOff.user.js)

#### Platform

Should work with any user script manager & any browser running JavaScript.
Tested using Opera with [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

#### Contact

For bugs, please post here. Comments are fine too.

---

Credit goes to [Oleg Valter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11407695) for working on the tricky parts.

Comment: Counter script: Turning Meta on - **Yes!**

Comment: @rene Follow the link ;) It's all your doing (mostly).. ;)

Comment: @rene how many lines of code does it have? :) 0? :)